# Skipping cells in IF/CountIf

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, formulas, excel-2016

I made this formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(D5:D8,">0")<>H5,"Yes","No")
```

It works fine, but I need the `COUNTIF` to skip 5 cells whenever I drag it down. So `D5:D8` would be `D10:D13` the next cell, then `D15:D18` and so on. I can't figure out how to do this and I really don't want to manually change 170+ cells.
If anyone could help I would really appreciate it.

Comment: What happens with `H5`? does it also go down 5 extra cells (i.e. `H5`, `H10` etc...)

Comment: H5 goes down incrementally by 1 so it's fine

Answer (score 1):

If you add a helper column next to your formula that runs in increments of 5, you can use OFFSET to get a drag down that would constantly offset the way you want: (J1 would be your helper column)

```
=IF(COUNTIF(OFFSET($D$5:$D$8,J1,0),">0")<>H5,"Yes","No")
```

This could also be bootlegged in the formula using (ROW(Reference on this Row)-Starting Row of Formula)*5

```
=IF(COUNTIF(OFFSET($D$5:$D$8,(ROW(J1)-1)*5,0),">0")<>H5,"Yes","No")
```

Comment: I tend to think ROW(1:1) makes it a bit more clear what's going on. But anyway, this is a good answer :) +1

Answer (score 1):

As @Wedge pointed out, [`OFFSET`](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/offset-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66) with [`ROW`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ROW-function-3A63B74A-C4D0-4093-B49A-E76EB49A6D8D)is a good way to go:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(OFFSET($D$5:$D$8,(ROW(1:1)-1)*5,0),">0")<>H5,"Yes","No")
```

---

*However*, `OFFSET` is a [volatile function](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm). It will slow down your workbook if you overuse it.

You can avoid this by using [`INDEX`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-A5DCF0DD-996D-40A4-A822-B56B061328BD) instead:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(INDEX(D:D,ROW(1:1)*5):INDEX(D:D,ROW(1:1)*5+3),">0")<>H5,"Yes","No")
```

Comment: Huh, I didn't even know INDEX could be used as a reference instead of a value like that. Just another bit of versatility it has over VLOOKUP I guess.

Comment: Wedge's solution did work but like you said having 170 formulas with OFFSET definitely slowed down the workbook. I'll have to try this out when I get back.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested but I believe the following should do the trick:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("D" & (ROW(I1)-1)*5+5):INDIRECT("D" & (ROW(I1)-1)*5+8),">0")<>H5,"Yes","No")
```

Assumptions: the formula is in column `I` and starts at `I1` you may need to adjust the `-1` after the row